# Why does Dockerfile use different syntax for RUN and CMD?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Just seems odd that in a Dockerfile a `RUN` line accepts plain bash like `apk add --no-cache python2 g++ make` but the `CMD` line takes the command like this `["node", "src/index.js"]`. What's the reason for this?

Comment: You can use the same form in `CMD` that you'd use in a `RUN`.

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run

Comment: Oh. I guess it's just all the tutorials including the official docker ones seem to always use this convention of using different styles in RUN vs CMD. Edit: I guess it makes since since RUN commands are more likely to be bash and CMD some arbitrary other executable.

Comment: The rationale of the two forms are explained down in the linked docs: _The exec form makes it possible to avoid shell string munging, and to RUN commands using a base image that does not contain the specified shell executable._ The exec form being the one in JSON `CMD ['foo', 'bar']`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`RUN`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run), [`CMD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd), and [`ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) all have the same syntax.  Both can take a [JSON array](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example) of individual command words, or a [bare string](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell-form-entrypoint-example) that is interpreted by a shell.  The linked Dockerfile documentation shows both forms for all three directives.

For `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT`, there are specific reasons to not want a shell (you may want to be clearer about which process is really process ID 1; you may be trying to use `CMD` as an argument list to an `ENTRYPOINT` process).  These don't really apply to `RUN`, though.  Conversely, `RUN` will frequently run multiple commands in sequence, which requires a shell to interpret.

```bash
# most common; '&&' requires a shell
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ...
# also legal; can only run one command, no environment variables or redirects
RUN ["make", "install"]

# both forms of CMD are legal and common
CMD ./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
CMD ["./manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]

# almost always wants to be JSON-array syntax
ENTRYPOINT ["bundle", "exec"]
# technically legal, but can't be passed a CMD and is hard to override
ENTRYPOINT bundle exec rails server
```